# How to send facebook session details to a rails application using facebooker plugin

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, facebooker

I am not able to integrate the iPhone application with my rails application both using fbconnect as the session details that i send along with the request from iPhone are not recognized by the facebooker plugin. The request from iPhone is as follows:

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:3000/i_phone/get-user-info?fb_sig_session_key=%@",session.sessionKey]]];

and in rails application i use

set_facebook_session

method from facebooker plugin.

Can someone tell me whay am i doing wrong here and what is the right way to do it.

---

I am requesting localhost as my web application is also hosted on the same machine locally.

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific? Why are you requesting localhost from an iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the ConnectiProxy demo put together by ckhsponge on github.  He's posted sample rails and iphone apps that work together to handle secure facebook connect authentication between iphone and rails.

Rails app
http://github.com/ckhsponge/connectiproxy

iPhone app
http://github.com/ckhsponge/facebook-iphone-sdk